# Customers can add variation to cart even when drop down menu not selected

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, e-commerce

I run a website that sells variants of the same product, allowing customers to select from a drop down menu to choose which one they want. [In this case](https://theapiary.co.nz/shop/skin-care/skin-care-cream/), choosing between 125ml and 250ml.

The problem is, customers can add a product to their cart, even if no size has been selected and it still says Please Select in the drop down field. In this case, the Starting From price will be added to the cart, and if a transaction goes through I have no way of knowing what size they actually wanted.

Is there any way I can block their ability to Add to Cart until they make a selection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes - that is the way amazon does it for some products especially when you have to choose both a size and color option. the buy button is disabled, there is a message above it to choose a size, and sometimes they won't show the price until you choose.

**However** - thats only for products with lots of different sizes - and you only have two sizes. So my suggestion would be - just put the two products on there: the size, the price, and a buy button for each one. Eliminate the drop down completely. You have plenty of room to do this and it will make it much easier for the customer to compare price/size, click and buy - which translates to more sales.

my other suggestion would be if possible to bring them to the cart page when they click to buy.  on the cart page tighten up the shipping options and put some other recommended products below that to encourage them to browse the store more. p.s. you have awesome products keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Great idea about the multiple products, but I'm adding an extra size to the creams and two new sizes to the honey in coming weeks, so AM a bit concerned it might look a little cluttered.

I've never got the shipping the way I want, but since this has all been created by me with no coding experience it'll take me a while to work out things like improving shipping, taking customers to checkout automatically, and my desired drop down menu thing. 

Wordpress has a recommended products section which has never seemed to work. Anyway, thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: if you don't have the select drop down you have *plenty of room* for more products. think about someone on a mobile phone having to do that drop down list -- and then wait to see the price. not good. since the price is different then i would strongly suggest breaking them out. The other issue is that many people will choose the smaller size and they won't even consider buying the larger size because they can't see it when they are making the purchase decision. whereas if they can see both sizes / prices - some people will then choose the larger one.

Comment: You don't need wordpress recommend whatever - to start out just put some links to products you want them to look at and maybe to your categories. Just keep in mind that many people will want to look at the actual cart page - not to checkout but just to confirm their order - and then shop some more. so its kind of like if you were in a market and you put one item in your basket - you don't want the storeclerk trying to hustle you out the door yet :-)